# Is it needed to have your blog title and description in H1 and H2

Tags: seo, website-design, blog

I have read an article that states that it is not necessary to have your blog title and description on your website at all.

Just have the titles of the posts in `h1`, on the index and the post page. And on the post page have your different sections started with `h2`.

Widget headers start with `h3`.

Title and description are most of the time in the logo image.

I have looked at the source of my favorite blog, http://net.tutsplus.com, and I see they do the same.

Is this recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to have your **blog title on every page** of the blog, but it doesn't need to be in h1, h2, etc. It can simply be in your header area. If you have an image use the site title as the alt text. Another method is to set the image as a background and use `<a href="http://example.com">Example site</a>` with a negative text-indent.

The `<h1>` tag should be the **title of the page**, not the site. For individual blog posts, this will be the post title. For your blog's home page, it could be the blog title or something like "Recent posts". Current concensus is to stick to one h1 per page, although HTML5 allows one per `<section>` tag.

Incidentally, the `<title>` tag should be pretty similar to `<h1>` i.e. the post title. It's usually favoured to add the site title to the end, e.g. "My awesome blog post | Blog Name". These two tags (title and h1) are among the most important for ranking.

As for `<h2>`, `<h3>` etc, you can **use as many as you'd like** on a page. They are for specifying a document hierarchy. On a blog you would normally use h2 for each major section of your article.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the world has definitely changed, but from an SEO perspective the golden rule was:

- 1 H1 per page.  This should be the title and contain the most important information (keyword)
- H2 have one for each sub topic that makes sense

In HTML5 it is perfectly acceptable to have an H1 per article on the page.

Comment: Ok so it's an html5 change, that makes sense. Are these changes already picked up by the mayor search engines, or is it recommended to just stick with the old system. New one makes more sense tho, because your websites title and description are already in you html head, no need to have them again on your page. And esp not for h1, and h2, because people don't come to your website for the title, they come to read your articles.

Answer (score 0):

Fretting about H? tags is a mostly meaningless SEO exercise. You'll find that there are plenty of ranking sites that don't use these tags at all or use them in non-standard ways. Think more about how using H? tags will ehnance the usability of your pages rather than how it might very marginally improve your ranking for a specific keyword.

There is even some indication that over-optimizing or over-using these tags (and meta-tags) for keywords may be one of several low quality page flags used by both Google and Bing to down rank sites. So, don't keyword stuff your tags and don't overdo them.

Answer (score -1):

It's **not needed** nor **must be**, but *recommended*, as I can recall...

And if my memory serves me well, recommendation are:

- **One H1** and **one H2** per page
- **Dynamic content** of H1 and H2, page-dependent

(for usage on page-snippets in search-engines results, if I'm correct), this way your get nice one-root tree for source-chart

From this POV, theme on main page net.tutsplus.com is far from SEO-ideal: 20 of H1 and none of h2

Comment: Yes this is the setup I remember. But in a lot of new articles I have read that the H1 tag is a tag for the most important headers on your page, can be more that one. Your website title and description are already handled in the head tag, <title>, <description>. Tutsplus is most of the time cutting edge, I am wondering if it is will be a good change to implement it that way. Hope to get some more answers.

Comment: description and keywords currently ignored (?) bt big players. And,  AFAIR, we get different ranking (?) for target keyword inside p and any H*. In case of big amount of H real keywords for page are hidden in other texts. I can be wrong here