# Blog name and tagline only in the footer, any SEO problems?

Tags: seo

I am creating a new blog, and I want to apply some new practices that come with html5. One thing I have seen is that the name of the blog and the tag line are wrapped in h2 an h3 respectively. The title of the posts on the page are wrapped in h1, as they are the most important elements on the page.

I stared a discussion about that here: [Is it needed to have your blog title and description in H1 and H2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21342/is-it-needed-to-have-your-blog-title-and-description-in-h1-and-h2)

Now I want to know how search engines will handle content that is placed in the footer section of the website.

I want to place the name of the blog in h2, and the tag line in h2, in the footer section of the website. Will this be picked up as important content for the website, or will this be regarded as lesser content than if it were in the header section.

In the header section there is already a logo image with the name of the blog, and I do not want to place any hidden content `{display:none}` on the website.

**Note** On the HOME page of the wesbite the blogname and title are already in the `<title>` and meta description of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in an H2 at the bottom of the page, and indeed repeated on every page, it will be considered lesser content.

With regards to HTML5 support, last time [I looked into this (back in July 2011)](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=15fdb84d2c769661&hl=en), the most definitive answer I could find on HTML5 support was this one:

> [Does semantic html5 matter to google yet?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2d4592cbb613e42c&hl=en)

Where the key point made by a Google Employee in October 2010 was:

> In general, we work hard to understand as much of the web as possible, but I have a feeling that HTML5 markup is not yet as widely in use (and in use correctly) that it would make sense for us to use it as a means of understanding content better. As HTML5 gains in popularity and as we recognize specific markup elements that provide value to our indexing system, this is likely to change, but at the moment I would not assume that you would have an advantage by using HTML5 instead of older variants.

I would personally recommend one of the following options:

1. On your homepage, have your site title as the H1, and the blog post titles as H2s, then on individual post pages, have the post titles as the H1 - this ensures that you have unique H1s on each page, as your homepage won't repeat your latest blog title, and the page title will match the H1, both of which are good for SEO - it's also semantically correct as on the homepage you will have multiple, equally important titles that are "children" of the homepage.
2. Have multiple H1s on the page - [this isn't as bad as is often thought from an SEO perspective (Google video on multiple H1s)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM) but might be an accessibility concern, and you won't have a matching title tag, so this will weaken the prominence of your site name in results.

I personally implemented a variant of 1. on my blog.

Comment: Really nice explanation. Will try to create an implantation based on on option 1. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a SEO perspective it's always better to have the website and page title at the beginning of your HTML document, just like in any other document you might ever publish.

But this won't stop you from graphically moving the headers to the bottom of your page with the use of CSS code ;-)